# rake db:seed issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm seeing a weird issue here when I run rake db:seed or rake db:migrate:

```
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/staging/config$ bundle show activeresource
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activeresource-3.0.3
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/staging/config$ rake db:seed
(in /home/rohan/Desktop/staging)
Could not find activesupport-3.0.3 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/staging/config$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]
```

I don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated. For the record, I am using RVM.

Comment: Have you tried running `bundle install`?

Comment: I have tried that yes and it seems to go through successfully (I get the output "using activeresource 3.0.3"). But nothing seems to have changed really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption that you tried running `bundle install` like it asked, you probably just need to use:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:seed
```

to run `rake` in the context of the bundle.

Comment: $ bundle exec rake db:seed
Could not find activesupport-3.0.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Still this issue exists. I don't know why! After doing a bundle install, I see the output "Using activeresource (3.0.3)".

Comment: `activeresource` is not `activesupport` - are they both listed when you `bundle install` ?

Answer (score 1):

Run `bundle install`. This will fix the problem.

Comment: nope, didn't help... it did bundle install successfully , outputted "Using activeresource (3.0.3) "

then when I try to run rake db:seed, same issue happens.

Answer (score 1):

you need to require rails in gemfile then run bundle install.

```
gem "rails", 'version'
```

now run `bundle install`